# Order of installing Big Data Modules on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

What is the order of installing Hadoop, Sqoop, Zookeeper, Spark, Java, Apache, Pig, Hive, Flume, Kafka, Mysql and other packages on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-20-04 or https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hadoop-ubuntu

Forget PIG, Flume, no longer relevant.

Zookeeper if running a Hadoop Cluster.

Then Spark, then Kafka. Mysql. But order here on this line not so relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you've mentioned, minus mysql, requires Java, so start there.

For high availability of HDFS, or Kafka, you need Zookeeper. Zookeeper has no dependencies, so that's next. (3 servers minimum for a production cluster)

Kafka can be setup next since it has no other dependencies. (Another 3 servers for high availability)

Hive requires a metastore, such as Mysql, so you'd then setup Mysql and run the Hive metastore schema queries on it. (at least 2 servers for read-write mysql replication)

HDFS can be next - multiple namenodes for high availability, datanodes, and YARN. (7 servers for 2 namenodes , 2 resource managers and 3 datanodes + nodemanagers)

Hive can optionally use HDFS, so that would be next, assuming you wanted to use it, and you can configure high availability on HDFS namenodes to Zookeeper. Presto or Spark are option that are faster than Hive and would also use the metastore. (2 HiveServers for high availability)

With YARN, HDFS, and Hive, you can setup Spark.

Flume would be next, but only if you actually needed it. Otherwise, code can be configured to write directly to Kafka.

Sqoop is a retired Apache project, and Spark can be used instead. Same for Pig.

In total, a minimal production-ready Hadoop cluster with Kafka and MySQL would require at least 17 servers. If you add load balancers and LDAP/Active Directory, then add more.

Comment: Many Thanks...This is a local installation on a Ubuntu Desktop. Is the above relevant for the same?

Comment: Yes. But you shouldn't run every service on one Desktop machine except for learning purposes only. You can use Apache Bigtop to simplify the installation. Worth pointing out that you need **at least** 16G of RAM to run all these services in one machine, and that's not including any Spark/MapReduce applications

Answer (score 0):

Just Install CDH (Cloudera) or Ambari on Ubuntu to install all Hadoop ecosystem modules as you mentioned and then install MySQL and Kafka separately to work with.

Comment: Thanks Shubham...This installation is for a local Ubuntu Desktop without VM. Am new to Big Data. Are the above CDH and Ambari modules relevant here?

Comment: Ambari is a retired Apache project and CDH Sandbox requires payment, last I checked

Comment: yes , Please follow link https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/install_cm_cdh.html#cmig_topic_6_6